# Shiny validate does not show error message

Tags: r, validation, shiny, reactive, shinyapps

My R Shiny app has two `textAreaInput()`, one for x values and the other for y values. When a button is pressed a simple linear regression model is fit and the results is printed on the mainPanel. This works perfectly fine.

I am trying to validate the `textAreaInput()` so I can show an error message

--- when the length(x) != length(y)

--- when the x or y boxes are empty

--- when the x or y boxes contains not enough values (less than two data pairs)

--- when the x or y boxes contains NA or invalid characters

Here a minimal reprex code. I see the Shiny validations for the above requirements are **not properly displaying on the mainPanel** when the conditions met. **EDITED CODE BELOW: Made the reprex code minimal and removed all `reactive()` as advised**

````
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyvalidate)

ui <- fluidPage(theme = bs_theme(version = 4, bootswatch = "minty"),
           
  navbarPage(title = div(span("Simple Linear Regression", style = "color:#000000; font-weight:bold; font-size:18pt")),

                tabPanel(title = "",
                  sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                      shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
                      id = "sideBar", 

                      textAreaInput("x", label = strong("x (Independent Variable)"), value = "87, 92, 100, 103, 107, 110, 112, 127", placeholder = "Enter values separated by a comma with decimals as points", rows = 3),
                      textAreaInput("y", label = strong("y (Dependent Variable)"), value = "39, 47, 60, 50, 60, 65, 115, 118", placeholder = "Enter values separated by a comma with decimals as points", rows = 3),

                      actionButton(inputId = "goRegression", label = "Calculate",
                                   style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),
                      actionButton("resetAllRC", label = "Reset Values",
                                   style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"), #, onclick = "history.go(0)"
                    ),
                    
                    mainPanel(
                      div(id = "RegCorMP",
                            textOutput("xArray"),
                            
                            textOutput("yArray"),
                          
                            textOutput("arrayLengths"),

                            verbatimTextOutput("linearRegression"),
                      ) # RegCorMP
                  ) # mainPanel
               ) # sidebarLayout
          )
      )
  )
  
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    # Data validation
    iv <- InputValidator$new()

    iv$add_rule("x", sv_required())
    iv$add_rule("y", sv_required())

    iv$enable()
    
    # String List to Numeric List
    createNumLst <- function(text) {
      text <- gsub("","", text)
      split <- strsplit(text, ",", fixed = FALSE)[[1]]
      as.numeric(split)
    }

    observeEvent(input$goRegression, {
      
      datx <- createNumLst(input$x)
      daty <- createNumLst(input$y)

      if(length(datx)<2){
        output$xArray <- renderPrint({
          "Not enough x values"
        })
      }
      
      else if(length(daty)<2){
        output$yArray <- renderPrint({
          "Not enough y values"
        })
      }
      
      if (length(datx) != length(daty)) {
        print(length(datx))
        print(length(daty))
        
        output$arrayLengths <- renderPrint({
          "Length of x and length of y must be the same"
        })
      }
     
      else if (length(datx) == length(daty)) {
          output$linearRegression <- renderPrint({ 
            summary(lm(daty ~ datx))
          })
      }
    })

    observeEvent(input$goRegression, {
      show(id = "RegCorMP")
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$resetAllRC, {
      hide(id = "RegCorMP")
      shinyjs::reset("RegCorMP")
    })
}
  
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)```
````

Comment: Nesting `reactive`is a recipe for disaster. That’s most likely your problem. Your `observeEvent` defines several `reactive`s within it. R’s usual scoping rules means those nested functions aren’t available to other elements of your app.

Comment: @Limey Any pointers on how to come out of the disaster? Do you mean I should use one separate `observeEvent` for every `reactive` statement?

Comment: No.  I mean I think you can get away with discarding the `observeEvent` *entirely*.  *ALL* your `reactive`s (and `observeEvent`s if needed) should be defined *directly* in the body of your server function.  I'm not going to attempt to do it because your code is _far_ from minimal: none of the CSS is directly relevant to your problem.  Nor is `MathJax`.  Nor the `radioButtons`.  And so on.  The "minimal" part of MRE is just as important as the "reproducible" part.  The discipline of creating a *minimal* reproducible example often allows me to solve a problem before posting a question.

Comment: @Limey Thanks for your advice, I have removed all the `reactive` and trimmed the code to a bare minimum. The validation messages are printing on the mainPanel although it also brings results along with the messages when the conditions are indeed met. Any tips on how to print one or the other, i.e., the warning or the correct results. Right now it is printing both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this comes close to what you want.  Note how *every* `reactive` is defined in the body of the server function, not within the body of another `reactive`.  **This is critical**.  And also removes the need for your `observeEvent` entirely.

I have removed more material (`div`s, `theme`s, etc)  that is not relevant to your question.  I'm not sure `shinyjs` is necessary either.  Also, I'm not sure what you're trying to do with your reset button (it appears to do nothing at the moment), so I've left it in.

I've added validation to ensure there are no NAs in either input, but have left it to you to implement a check for equality of length.

As an aside, there's no need to comma separate your inputs: spaces would suffice... ;=)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyvalidate)

ui <- fluidPage(
        useShinyjs(),
        navbarPage(
          title = "Simple Linear Regression",
          tabPanel(
            title = "",
            sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
              id = "sideBar", 
              textAreaInput(
                "x", 
                label = strong("x (Independent Variable)"), 
                value = "87, 92, 100, 103, 107, 110, 112, 127", 
                placeholder = "Enter values separated by a comma with decimals as points", 
                rows = 3
              ),
              textAreaInput(
                "y", 
                label = strong("y (Dependent Variable)"), 
                value = "39, 47, 60, 50, 60, 65, 115, 118", 
                placeholder = "Enter values separated by a comma with decimals as points", 
                rows = 3
              ),
              actionButton(
                inputId = "goRegression", 
                label = "Calculate",
              ),
              actionButton(
                "resetAllRC", 
                label = "Reset Values",
              )
            ),
            mainPanel(
              div(
                textOutput("xArray"),
                textOutput("yArray"),
                textOutput("arrayLengths"),
                verbatimTextOutput("linearRegression"),
              ) # RegCorMP
            ) # mainPanel
          ) # sidebarLayout
        )
      )
    )

server <- function(input, output) {
  # Data validation
  iv <- InputValidator$new()
  iv$add_rule("x", sv_required())
  iv$add_rule("x", ~ if (any(is.na(as.numeric(strsplit(., ",", fixed = FALSE)[[1]])))) "NAs are not allowed")
  iv$add_rule("y", sv_required())
  iv$add_rule("y", ~ if (any(is.na(as.numeric(strsplit(., ",", fixed = FALSE)[[1]])))) "NAs are not allowed")
  iv$enable()
  # See https://rstudio.github.io/shinyvalidate/articles/advanced.html for clues on
  # how to implement length(x) == length(y) validation

  createNumLst <- function(text) {
    text <- gsub("","", text)
    split <- strsplit(text, ",", fixed = FALSE)[[1]]
    d <- as.numeric(split)
    if (length(d) < 2) "Not enough values"
    d
  }
  
  xData <- reactive({
    createNumLst(input$x)
  })
  
  yData <- reactive({
    createNumLst(input$y)
  })
  
  output$xArray <- renderPrint({ xData() })

    output$yArray <- renderPrint({ yData() })
  
  output$arrayLengths <- renderPrint({
    if (length(xData()) != length(yData())) "Length of x and length of y must be the same"
  })
  
  # Use isolate to ensure that results are updated only when action button is clicked, not 
  # every time the input data changes
  output$linearRegression <- renderPrint({
    input$goRegression
    isolate({
      summary(lm(yData() ~ xData()))
    })
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$goRegression, {
    show(id = "RegCorMP")
  })
  
  # Not sure what you are trying to do here
  observeEvent(input$resetAllRC, {
    hide(id = "RegCorMP")
    shinyjs::reset("RegCorMP")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the replies. `divs`, `themes`, `shinyjs` etc are all useful for a more mature Shiny app that I am working on [link](https://cougarstats.shinyapps.io/CougarStats/). This particular post was a small piece of it where I was working on **Simple Linear Regression** and wanted to validate `x` and `y` `textAreaInput` fields. The Reset button is supposed to clear everything (output, warnings, plots etc) currently displayed on the mainPanel.

Comment: " divs, themes, shinyjs etc are all useful for a more mature Shiny app that I am working on link".  That's all perfectly reasonable.  But they are *not* relevant to the question you asked.